# Google API blocked my app ip address and returns CAPTCHA

Tags: api, google-api, recaptcha, captcha

My app uses Google API and it worked well for a long time but recently Google blocked the IP address of my server for about an hour and every response to the API was as follows: *Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network.  This page checks to see if it's really you sending the requests, and not a robot...* - they attached CAPTCHA form field as html.

My app is also an API so CAPTCHA can not be done because it is in json format (HTML in json cannot be rendered).

Only app users sends requests so I have a little control over it. Of course, I limit the number of requests per user, but it was not the case. Limits at google console are also fine.

I wonder how can I prevent this happening in the future? Is there any way I can ask them directly? Have you experienced this?

Comment: Unless a google employee happens to see this, I'm not sure how you would expect us to know the answer to this. Try to find a contact at Google to talk to.

Comment: Maybe someone have experienced the same issue - that is why I wrote this topic.